# How to insert html on javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need your help guys im new on javascript or jquery im trying to add a html code inside the overlay element but its not working im using  $( "overlay" ).append( "**Hello**" ); this one but its not working

the js below outputs   what im trying to do is to input an html code inside it

```
 init=()=>{
        //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
        document.querySelector('a.menuToggle, a#welcomeDivs').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
    }
    modal={
        overlay:{
            init:()=>{
                //CREATE OVERLAY 
                var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
                overlay.id = 'welcomeDivsss';
                //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
                overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);
            $( "overlay" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );

                //APPEND TO INTERFACE
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

            },
            remove:(e)=>{
                //REMOVE ITSELF
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
            }       
        }
    }

    //ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

Comment: can you show us the html code where you are looking to append the new code? Is "overlay" an id value? if it were, it should be `$("#overlay")`

Comment: the code output <overlay id="welcomeDivsss"> </overlay> on the html file. what im trying to do sr is to add an html code inside overlay @Webeng

Comment: I see, let me know if my answer worked for you techno

Comment: @Webeng No :( nothing is showing up event this $("#welcomeDivsss").html("<h1>hi</h1>");

Comment: You are trying to append html to overlay before it is appended to body. Refer to the given answer.

Comment: an `<overlay>` tag doesn't exist in html. Try using `<div id="welcomeDivsss"></div>` and then use the same code as in my answer. Let me know if that fixes it for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to append html to overlay before it is appended to body.
Following is updated code.

```
 init=()=>{
        //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
        document.querySelector('a.menuToggle, a#welcomeDivs').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
    }
    modal={
        overlay:{
            init:()=>{
                //CREATE OVERLAY 
                var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
                overlay.id = 'welcomeDivsss';
                //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
                overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);

                //APPEND TO INTERFACE
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

                // After overlay added to html. "welcomeDivsss" is overlay id you specified.
                $( "#welcomeDivsss" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );

            },
            remove:(e)=>{
                //REMOVE ITSELF
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
            }       
        }
    }

    //ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

Comment: Wow! thats amazing youre awesome

Answer (score 2):

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('welcomeDivsss').innerHTML = "<h1>hi</h1>";
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#welcomeDivsss").html("<h1>hi</h1>");
```

---

**Edited:** It is also possible that you are trying to use your JavaScript code before the specific html element is loaded. Below is the same code as above but with the code that tells the browser to only execute the JavaScript after the page has fully loaded:
**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('welcomeDivsss').innerHTML = "<h1>hi</h1>";
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#welcomeDivsss").html("<h1>hi</h1>");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JQuery's 
.html()
 function:

```
$("overlay").html("<strong>Hello</strong>");
```